# How to use Redux to change url and render another components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm a little bit confuse about Redux. or if have a good example for this.  please help me

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Please include anything you have done so far. And read [How To Ask A Proper Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

For sure it is hard to help with no details at all... :)

From what you say in your question, I don't see the point between using redux and changing the url to render a component. You can render a component via a route using react-router but it is not linked with redux...

If you want to use your data in the store to render your appropriate component then you need to bit more talkative...